# Should we always have a KAFKA_LISTENERS (inside and outside) specified even if the producer and consumer are on the same n/w?

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka

what if the containers(producer, consumer and kafka) are on the same n/w bridge?
I am new to kafka, just trying to run a simple producer and consumer example. I have a docker container which produces messages and pushes it to kafka (this works with by declaring kafka:9092 as a bootstrap server. Since my docker container for kafka is called kafka)

Do i still need to declare inside and outside ports for kafka? Cant the consumer listen to the same port as producer?

Using kafka-python to send and receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

Consumers and producers don't listen on ports, but as long as you have (at least) `PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092` as the advertised listener, and `listeners` includes port 9092, then you don't necessarily need any other listener.

However, if you add other brokers in the same network for replication, I'd strongly recommend using at least SASL_PLAINTEXT for the inter-broker communication. That way all brokers in the same network "trust" each other as a cluster (and you can fine tune network traffic for replication, but that's not really needed for Docker)